# hg clone using mercurial throws "getaddrinfo failed" error (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, mercurial, clone, bitbucket

I have created a public repository on bit bucket website. I can run the clone command from outside the office network (LAN).

But it is not working inside the office network. I am suspecting it is to do with firewall or proxy settings. I can access the URL from browser window (IE9/Chrome).

Please help in fixing this problem. Thanks.

Command:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/gbsandeep/test2

abort: error: getaddrinfo failed
```

PS: I went through other posts but it did not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you might need to tell Mercurial what your proxy settings are. First hit for "mercurial proxy":

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/05/13/mercurial-pulling-from-behind-a-proxy/

If you need to figure out what settings to use, you should probably look at what your IE settings are, e.g. by going to the `Internet Properties | Connections | LAN Settings` dialog.

Comment: Thanks jjlin. It was a direct command. I am feeling dumb now :)

Comment: It also gives you this error if you get the URL to clone from wrong, in my case I had mis-spelled the domain name.

Answer (score 6):

If you find yourself on this page because you've hit a `getaddr` error when using the `hg-git` plugin with a username, it is likely that you've hit the [Fails with username in URL (getaddreinfo failed)](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/issues/164/fails-with-username-in-url-getaddreinfo) bug.

Thus:

```
$ hg clone https://foo@stash/
abort: error: getaddrinfo failed
$ hg clone https://stash/
http authorization required for http://stash.....
realm: Atlassian Stash
user: ...
```

(Doesn't solve the original user's issue, but can be a cause of the same symptoms).

Comment: Who may thought that having username in repo name will fail in case of `hg-git`... That's definitely a proper solution.

Comment: It worked when I removed the username from URL 
ssh://username@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git
Removing the first username helped fix the error
ssh://bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the `http_proxy` environment variable. (worked for me, after of 5 hours of headache).

Answer (score 4):

Pls check whether you can access the repository directly first. e.g from web browser

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to **set** `http_proxy` env var.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm mercurial clone dialog that was resolved by enabling the corporate vpn and setting up automatically detecting the proxy in Win 10. However, the PyCharm throwed some new exception like this:

6:03 PM Clone failed
                Clone from ***your url here*** failed.
                ** Unknown exception encountered with possibly-broken third-party extension hg4ideapromptextension
                ** which supports versions unknown of Mercurial.
                ** Please disable hg4ideapromptextension and try your action again.
                ** If that fixes the bug please report it to the extension author.
                ** Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
                ** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.7.1)
                ** Extensions loaded: strip, mq, hg4ideapromptextension
                Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "hg", line 41, in